# Conditions In evets in wpf (XMAL)

Tags: wpf, events, conditional-statements

I need to change the height of tabcontrol.
How can I use condition in XAML?
In case of height 180- I need to do change the height to 30
In case of height 30- I need to do change the height to 180

> ```
>             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="btnOpenState">
>                 <EventTrigger.Actions>
>                     <BeginStoryboard>
>                         <Storyboard>
>                             <DoubleAnimation
>                                 Storyboard.TargetName="tbViews" 
>                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
>                                 From="30" To="181" Duration="0:0:1" 
>                                 AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
>                         </Storyboard>
>                     </BeginStoryboard>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use binding and an `IValueConverter` to do this.  (Note that you don't need to set `From` in the Storyboard if the target is already set to that value.)

```
To="{Binding ElementName=tbViews,Path=Height,Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}}"
```

Here *HeightConverter* should implement `IValueConverter`, returning for the conversion `((double)value < 180) ? 180 : 30`.